# How to split a date into day, month and year

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a date in this format - `31­Jan­2020`, how do I get the day, month and year - 31, Jan and 2020.

I am looping through a dataframe and the name of the date column is `date`. This is what I am doing

```
for index,row in data.iterrows():
    date = row['date']
    print(date)
```

Comment: Please post proper details of the question, like, you want to format this in Pandas or Python? Also, please share your attempt.

Comment: @MayankPorwal I have added more details.

Comment: Please share your sample dataframe and expected output based on it.

Comment: I just showed you what date returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should work in Python:

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

date_str = '31Jan2020'

a_date = dt.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d%b%Y').date()

print(a_date.year)
print(a_date.month)
print(a_date.day)

data_df = pd.DataFrame([['31Jan2020'], ['1Jan2020']], columns=['date_str'])

data_df['year'] = data_df['date_str'].map(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%d%b%Y').date().year)
data_df['month'] = data_df['date_str'].map(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%d%b%Y').date().month)
data_df['day'] = data_df['date_str'].map(lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, '%d%b%Y').date().day)

print(data_df)
```

Comment: Can you check my question? I added more details. Maybe you can edit your answer as the current answer don't work for me.
Thanks

Comment: I tried the first option and got ValueError: time data '31\xadJan\xad2020' does not match format '%d%b%Y'

Comment: Try: `dt.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%d\xad%b\xad%Y').date()`